# google maps api 3: how to solve error of "unexpected token <"?

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, meteor, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to put my working code of google maps initialization inside meteor project and get two errors which are `Unexpected token <` and `initMap is not a function`. The code of html file I am giving below:

```
<head>
  <title>simple</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Welcome to Meteor!</h1>

  {{> hello}}
  {{> info}}
    <script src="main.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBNRzOGCsGk5u0VHjDOh_4QyJf4K-Hz5Bw&signed_in=true&libraries=places&callback=initMap"
    async defer></script>
</body>

<template name="hello">
  <button>Click Me</button>
  <p>You've pressed the button {{counter}} times.</p>
</template>

<template name="info">
  <h2>Learn Meteor!</h2>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="https://www.meteor.com/try">Do the Tutorial</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://guide.meteor.com">Follow the Guide</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://docs.meteor.com">Read the Docs</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://forums.meteor.com">Discussions</a></li>
  </ul>
</template>
```

Comment: `Unexpected token <` where? What line of which file? Is it in `main.js?` The debugger should tell you that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this package from atmospherejs
[dburles:google-maps](https://atmospherejs.com/dburles/google-maps)

The documentation is well explained.

You don't need to add main.js, meteor will take care for that.

You can see this sample too [example](https://github.com/dburles/meteor-google-maps-demo)

Answer (score 0):

you cannot add `google maps` api like that in meteor applications. There is a package available which will help you integrate maps into your application

[dburles:google-maps](https://atmospherejs.com/dburles/google-maps)